# How to convert html page to a pdf using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to convert html page into pdf and using javascript from another html page using a button click and then send that pdf on the email

like i have a html page index.html which contain a button and that button will convert the second html page which is pdf.html and that pdf file i want to send on the email

Comment: This would be very difficult to do in JS and required PHP (and not the easiest PHP either)

Comment: I'm following this question, as I've only managed to do this using server-side tools, or telling the user to install a specific add-on/extension into browser.  The client side add-on worked the best, but there are good paid for server side tools.  Interested to see if anyone can suggest anything for you in JS though.

Comment: Actullally i am using firebase

Comment: To email this out, i would suggest looking at generating pdf on server, as you will email it from server.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there are several options, one of them is the next:

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
<!-- HTML contnet goes here -->
```

JS:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
var elementHTML = $('#contnet').html();
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#elementH': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};
doc.fromHTML(elementHTML, 15, 15, {
    'width': 170,
    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
});

// Save the PDF
doc.save('sample-document.pdf');
```

Comment: If we can convert it to the pdf at client side then we can send that pdf to email not to save it on the client pc

Comment: I think it will not include css which i have applied

Answer (score 0):

**jsPDF** is a client-side JS application that generates PDF. I personally haven't used it but this looks promising and seems to be actively maintained.

Web site: https://parall.ax/products/jspdf
GitHub Repo: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

A Medium article that explains the basics: https://medium.com/@w3bh4ck/generating-pdf-from-the-client-side-with-jspdf-5ea34391bfa2

Comment: you've missed the 'e' of your description text "Designer who writes front-end cod"  - just letting you know bud